# ion icons not showing up on ipad / edge

Tags: ipad, microsoft-edge, stenciljs, ionicons

I have a stenciljs component deployed in an nginx server behind an authentication service. In order to get anything the request must include a cookie containing an access_token. the component is dipslyaed with no preoblem on android devices and on chrome/firfox/IE11/ in desktop devices. the problem is with microsoft edge and on ipad (any navigator) and its due to the browser not sending the cookie to the server. Any hint ?

header.tsx

```
import { Component, Prop, State, Element } from '@stencil/core';
@Component({
  tag: 'pm-header',
  styleUrl: 'pm-header.scss',
  shadow: true
})
export class PmHeader {

...

  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li id="menu-icon" class="left menu-icon"
            onClick={() => this.toggleFocus('menu-icon')} >
            <a>
              <ion-icon name="md-apps"></ion-icon>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li id="user-icon" class="right menu-icon"
            onClick={() => this.toggleFocus('user-icon')} >
            <a>
              <ion-icon name="md-contact"></ion-icon>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

PS: I'm using stencil/core v0.15.2

Comment: @ malek, I suggest you to provide a code sample to produce the issue. We will try to produce the issue on our side and try to find any possible solution or a work around. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I posted some code sample, if there is any additional information that I can provide, please tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some digging it turned out that the issue is with ionicons implementation.
They fetch the svgs without sending the credentials which result in an authenticated request. Of course some navigator such as chrome and firefox and even IE11 manages to send the cookies even though it's not explicitly specified that they should.
Anyway, to solve this I had to create a script file that run after the build. This script adds credentials: "include" option to the fetch call so that the cookie get sent.

fix-icons-script.js

```
/** 
 * Workaround to fix this ion-icons bug https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/issues/640
 * To be removed when this bug is fixed
 */
const fs = require('fs');
const workDir = 'dist/component-dir';

fs.readdir(workDir, function(err, items) {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }

  for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].endsWith('.entry.js')) {
      insertString(workDir + '/' + items[i], '"force-cache"', ',credentials:"include"');
    }
  }
});

function insertString(file, searchValue, insertValue){
  fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, content) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }

    let newContent = content.substr(0, content.indexOf(searchValue) + searchValue.length);
    content = content.substr(newContent.length, content.length); 
    newContent += insertValue + content;

    fs.writeFile(file, newContent, function (err) {
      if (err) { return console.log(err); }
      console.log('Successfully rewrote ' + file);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: @ malek, From your last post. i can see that you had found the solution for your issue and posted it as an answer. I suggest you to mark that answer as an accepted answer for this question may help other community members in future. thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Tried to do it when I posted the answer but it wasn't possible until 24h after the answer is posted, thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: Thanks for your kind efforts for marking the answer for this thread.